# How to build cpp file which name has a special character by CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, g++, mingw

I'm learning CMake.I found a problem, when i try to build a cpp file which name has a special character(such as "[155]test_file.cpp").The compiler can't find this file.How can i solve this problem by modifying CMakeLists,rather than rename the file?

I'm testing in a window10 PC,and compiler is mingw.

## error info

g++.exe: error: E:\test[155]test_file.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(TEST_ LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(test_ "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/[155]test_file.cpp")
```

Comment: According to that output it seems like the slash between your file name and the source directory was lost when generating the project. Just out of curiosity: why do you specify an absolute path? It seems like `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` are identical here which would allow you to use relative paths. Using `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is usually not a good idea, since this could break the project if you ever decide to use `add_subdirectory` to add the directory containing this `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: yes,it was lost. I gauss it seems relation to the cmake's  bracket syntax.  And thanks for your reminder, it is just a test case.